# No module named http_client error when trying to run django with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest

I am trying to create a simple API using django rest framework. In the view i have the following code.

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from moviestash.models import Movie
from moviestash.serializer import MovieSerializer
from rest_framework import generics

#List all movies and add movies
class MovieList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

#Get a movie and delete a movie
class MovieDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

when i run the server and try to go to any url i get the following error.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'moviestash',
 'south',
 'rest_framework')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "N:\Python\movies_api\movies_api\urls.py" in <module>
  10.     url(r'^movies/', include('moviestash.urls')),
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "N:\Python\movies_api\moviestash\urls.py" in <module>
  3. from . import views
File "N:\Python\movies_api\moviestash\views.py" in <module>
  4. from rest_framework import generics
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py" in <module>
  8. from rest_framework import views, mixins
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in <module>
  14. from rest_framework.response import Response
File "N:\Python\venvs\rest_api\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py" in <module>
  8. from django.utils.six.moves.http_client import responses

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named http_client
```

When i go into the django shell and i can perform the following import with no issue from django.utils.six.moves import http_client. Also after i import http_client i also performed a dir(http_client) and i can see the responses object, but for some reason when i try to import using from django.utils.six.moves.http_client import responses i get an ImportError: No module named http_client. This is very frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting [issue 2969](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2969). It should work if you upgrade from Django 1.6 to 1.6.11. However, please note that 1.6 is now end of life and does not receive security fixes, so ideally you should upgrade to the latest supported version of Django or the latest LTS.